# SVG: Is it possible to change predefined line shape to circle like shape with attributes and CSS

Tags: svg, line

Is it possible to change SVG's predefined shape `line` to a round circle like shape(not to a `circle` element) with attributes and CSS? I mean we don't change the `line` tag to `circle` tag but just change some styles and attributes to make it looks like a round circle.

I tried `stroke-linecap` attribute but seems I missed something.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="210" width="500">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="30" y2="0" stroke-linecap="round" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:40" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Can you tell me how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  Is it that you are confused why your round caps are not showing properly?  If that's not it, what do you mean exactly by "transform"?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau, sorry for my poor English, I mean convert line's shape to a round circle, will modify my question soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codepen.io/a10k/pen/ModQzq

`<svg height="210" width="500">
  <line x1="100" y1="100" x2="100" y2="100" stroke-linecap="round" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:40" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>`

You achieved what you want, you just positioned the line in a corner so it doesn't look like a circle as it is trimmed.